# Why For loop not working in javascript using keyup function?

Tags: javascript, html, keyup

When i enter the amount in the text box it goes to function and not working for loop.

I have one table it shows multiple dynamic rows.

Rows count only count.value in function(javascript)

And then because of this multiple row only i want loop to add price (rec_qty*porate)

HTML

```
<?php
$table=mysql_query("SELECT * from purchase_order");
while($table1=mysql_fetch_array($table))
{   
  $i++;

<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" id="tatalrecord" value="<?php echo $i;?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control rec_qty" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="rec_qty"></td>

<td><input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control porate" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="porate"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
  var count = document.getElementById("tatalrecord");
  var cn = count.value;
  alert(count.value);
    for(var i = 0; i < cn; ++i)
    {
      alert("hi");
      var x = document.getElementById("rec_qty");
      var y = document.getElementById("porate");
      var z = x.value * y.value;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: What shows alert(count.value)?

Comment: And where is `#tatalrecord` ?

Comment: does it even `alert('hi')`

Comment: Why are you going in `loop` ?

Comment: if i hide for loop it shows correct count. count value is by table rows. so the count value is not problem.

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/bzdL9hkr/

Comment: Did you typo totalrecord as tatalrecord perhaps?

Comment: I think @Rayon made a point.. You're doing **same** operations for `cn` times. Why would you go for loop?

Comment: that parseint works in forloop but shows first value only, thanks adeneo and nitya kumar

Comment: **`id` must be unique.** `document.getElementById("rec_qty")` returns the first element in the document with that id, not the one in the current row. (Even if `id` didn't have to be unique, you haven't done anything to try to distinguish between them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Price </td>
<td> Quantity </td>
<td> Total  </td>
<tr>
<?php  
  $table = mysql_query("select * from table_name");
  $i=0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table))
  {
?>
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="hidden" id="tatalrecord" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="porate<?php echo $i; ?>" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="rec_qty<?php echo $i; ?>" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
  <td> <input type="text" readonly="" id="total"> </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var z = 0;
  var count = document.getElementById("tatalrecord");
  var cn = (count.value) ? parseInt(count.value) : 0;
  alert(cn);
  for (var i = 1; i <= cn; ++i)
  {
     var x = document.getElementById("rec_qty"+i);
     var y = document.getElementById("porate"+i);
     z = parseInt(x.value) * parseInt(y.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var z = 0;
  var count = document.getElementById("tatalrecord");
            var cn = (count.value) ? parseInt(count.value) : 0;
            alert(count.value);
            for (var i = 0; i < cn; ++i)
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("rec_qty");
                var y = document.getElementById("porate");
                 z = parseInt(x.value) * parseInt(y.value);
            }
  
  
  document.getElementById("total").value = z
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script> 
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <input type="text" style="width:45px" value='2' id="tatalrecord">
<td><input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control rec_qty" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="rec_qty"></td>

<td><input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control porate" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="porate"></td>
</tr>
</table>
  
  total : <input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control porate" value="0" id="total">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you keep posting more answers? You can use the [edit] link to update your original answer... In any case, it would be helpful if you were to [edit] the answer to explain what you've changed and why that was necessary. (By the way, you don't need `parseInt()`, because the `*` operator converts its operands to numeric.)

Comment: check One total field added in last

Comment: have you got your answer ?

Comment: no .... i think the problem is in input type id="rec_qty" if it is dynamic means the problem solved. But i dont know how to get different values during loop

Comment: Thanks @shruthi ..
you should create dynamic ID for multiple use (id use unique always not duplicate ) in your case i hope id is duplicated.

and use class name instead of id

Comment: if i use dynamic id like rec_qty1, rec_qty2 means how can i wrote this line var x = document.getElementById("rec_qty"); either by this var x = document.getElementById("rec_qty"+i); or something. Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shruti i tried to shorted out your problem i had created own table to assume table row

hope this code will help you ....

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {

          // var count = document.getElementById("tatalrecord");

          //Total no of rows in your table
          var cn =  document.getElementById("tatalrecord").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

          console.log(cn);

            for(var i = 0; i < cn; ++i)
            {
              console.log("hi");
              alert('hi');
              var x = document.getElementById("rec_qty");
              var y = document.getElementById("porate");
              var z = x.value * y.value;
              console.log(z);
            } 
         }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table id="tatalrecord">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        </table>

        <input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control rec_qty" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="rec_qty">
        <input type="text" style="width:45px" class="form-control porate" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="porate">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```